# JS wai-aria and dynamic content loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wai-aria

I'm writing an web application which uses `twitter bootstrap` and `aria`. I have table with sort option which looks: [image: http://scr.hu/0ti4/4m3b7]. 
My content is dynamically loading into `#content div` with `jQuery.html()` function. When I hit `F5` everything works fine, but after I load content by jQuery to my div which contains these tables, something goes wrong. Tables loses their search options and pagination bars.. like this: [image: http://scr.hu/0ti4/42lll].

There are few functionality which stop working too. How should I load dynamic content into my `#content div`?

**My current code:**

```
this.getContent = function(page){
    var self = this;
    $('#center-column').removeAttr("class");
    if (page.indexOf('&') > 0)
        $('#center-column').addClass( page.substr(0, page.indexOf('&') ) );
    else $('#center-column').addClass( page );

    $.get( $('body').attr('id')+".php?page="+page+"&mode=ajax",
        function(data){
            self.fetchData( data );
        }, "json");
}

this.fetchData = function(data){
    if (data.redirect_url != null)
        window.location = data.redirect_url;
    $("#content").html( data.html );
}
```

Is there any method aria has and I should call after I change content of my div dynamicly?

Comment: Are you getting any error in firebug console, when the functionality doesnt work ?

Comment: I'm using chrome, but no.. I don't have nothing in console.

Comment: Can u create a fiddle for your scenario, will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

> after I load content by jQuery to my div which contains these tables, something goes wrong. Tables loses their search options and pagination bars

Use `.wrap` to add dynamic content around the existing markup:

```
$("#content").html(  $(data.html).wrap("#content")  )
```

> Is there any method aria has and I should call after I change content of my div dynamicly?

Use the `aria-live` attribute to indicate the content is dynamic, and `assertive` as the value.

```
$("#content").attr("aria-live", "assertive")
```

**References**

- [JSON-ARIA](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Accessibility/JSON_ARIA)
- [Using ARIA role=alert or Live Regions to Identify Errors](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_Live_Regions_or_role%3Dalert_to_Identify_Errors)
- [Choosing Between Special Case Live Regions](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#chobet)
- [aria-live (property)](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-live)
- [ARIA Practices: Managing Dynamic Changes](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#docmgt_header)